# Dotnet exe fails on system with 4 processors

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, cpu-cores, winpe

I have a WPF exe which crashes on a system with 4 Intel procs (56 core each). The same exe works fine if we disable multi threading or reduce the core count to 24 on each proc.

The dotnet framework used is 4.8. And the exe is run in WinPE environment.

Have tried the below config based on this old thread ([Does .NET Core have a 64 vCPU limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61127665/does-net-core-have-a-64-vcpu-limit)). Though the core count changed from 64 to 448 (HyperThreading enabled), the app still crashes.

```
`<configuration>
   <runtime>
      <Thread_UseAllCpuGroups enabled="true"/>
      <GCCpuGroup enabled="true"/>
      <gcServer enabled="true"/>
   </runtime>
</configuration>`
```

Is there any other setting or config that is needed to make the exe work with more than 96 cores?

Comment: Appreciate some guidance on this at the earliest. We are blocked due to this issue.

Comment: at first, notice I'm not familiar with multi-proc machines and this is a shot in the dark. I remember to have heard s.th. about garbage collection issues to be aware of on multi-processor. Give disabling [gcConcurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/gcconcurrent-element) a chance.